# able to scale container with global mode in docker?

Tags: docker, scale, global, swarm

I have three swarm nodes.
Deployed containerized service with mode "global" through docker swarm.

Later, add one more swarm node to current to be four nodes.
How can i deploy the container service to new added nodes?

The command(docker service scale) only be used with "replicated" mode.

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend running the following command if you have a lot of services running. This command will rebalance all services evenly across all the docker nodes.

```
docker service ls -q > docker_services && for i in `cat docker_services`; do docker service update "$i" --detach=false --force ; done
```

In case you have only one service then use this command

```
docker service update <service_name>
```

Comment: Or `docker stack deploy -c file.yml stackname` updates all services of stack

Comment: Yes another using the stack deploy.